# > is not encoded in an xml attribute using cfxml

Tags: xml, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am attempting to encode > in an attribute of xml. It appears the xmlformat function I am using properly encodes it, but the cfxml tag then converts back to >. CDATA does not have any effect on the conversion either. This is just a simple markup of what I am doing. The > stays encoded when used outside of the attribute, but not in the attribute.

```
<cfxml variable="xmlObject" casesensitive="yes">
<someXML> 
    <cfoutput>
        <someElement someAttribute="![CDATA[#XmlFormat("Body of element with <, >, "" and & goes here.", "true")#]]">  
            #XmlFormat("Body of element with <, >, "" and & goes here.", "true")# 
        </someElement> 
    </cfoutput>
</someXML>
```

```
<cfcontent type="text/xml">
<cfsavecontent variable="xmlDownLoad">
    <cfoutput>#toString(xmlObject)#</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfcontent type="text/plain" variable="#ToBinary(ToBase64(xmlDownLoad))#">
```

Comment: Why is this a problem?  The only place where `>` has to be escaped in XML is when it's part of the sequence `]]>` - anywhere else it's fine for it to appear as a literal `>`

Comment: The customer I'm writing for is insisting it needs to be encoded. Although I have several replies agreeing it doesn't, at this point I need supporting documentation or to fulfill the request.

Comment: The customer is wrong as far as XML is concerned. They may be right as far as the code they're using to consume the XML is concerned, but that would be a bug in their XML. If they really insist, you can either build a modified XML serializer or a text-based postprocessor... Be sure to bill them for the extra work.

Comment: The "supporting documentation" is [this section of the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax).